There is an implant in me, is there a way to identify the frequency it is broadcasting signals on?
This question is very similar to my issue here, except my predicament is the exact opposite. Regardless of the plausibility, veracity, or my mental health, let's posit the existence of an unwanted implant in my body. Unlike the linked question, however, this chip/implant most likely has broadcast capabilities. More specifically, it can hear/read/listen to my inner mental voice in my mind to a reasonably high fidelity.
I'm making the assumption that the chip does not operate via induction. I figure a device that is sophisticated enough to perform this feat needs more power to operate than induction could provide. This "mind reading" happens wherever I go (at least, all around New York City. I live in Queens), so that would imply that there isn't a hidden induction generator hidden in the vicinity of my home, which further suggests that the chip must broadcast on its own to transmit my brain waves out for reading. However, I could be wrong.
My main goal is this: how can I, to a reasonably confident degree, prove or disprove whether or not there's a device broadcasting from somewhere in my body (preferably using methods easily accessible to a layman, please don't tell me to "get an MRI"), and on what frequency band?
Also, unlike the poster in the linked question, there is nothing I wish to keep secret regarding this device, so feel free to ask any questions you may have. The people who answered that question seemed to be genuinely trying to help the other poster rather than dismissing him outright, and I hope to receive the same kindness.

To the best of my knowledge such a device does not exist and the and the likelihood of something implanted in and operating without you knowing is basically zero.
I understand that you feel otherwise, so lets try to analyze the problem a bit: I've personally worked on devices that are inside or closely attached to the human body and one of the biggest problems is simply power. Thousands of engineers have worked on this for a long time and the status quo is not all that impressive: Either it's a battery or an induction loop. The battery needs to be replaced regularly and any induction connection requires a VERY close physical connection between the two loops. Nothing about this is subtle and re-powering without you noticing is quite impossible.
Since you assume that the device is transmitting when you are out and about, it would require a fair bit of power and frequent re-powering's. One of the more reasonable radio solutions for such a device would be Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), which could transmit to a nearby phone. A typically battery for such a device is about the size of an M&M (ca. 0.5 cm^3, 1cm diameter) and they last for 3-4 hours before they need recharging.

please don't tell me to "get an MRI"

What's wrong with that? Any device capabale of what you describe would need some amount of metal and a power source. If you are really worried you can get an MRI, a CT or even just an X-ray. Have you flown recently? For example pacemakers (and their battery packs) do show up on metal detectors and body scanners.  This may be a quick and cheap way to get a scan. A round trip from JFK to BOS is less than $120.

I'm aware of it, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question. I'm also aware that functional microprocessors can be made incredibly tiny these days, to the point of being invisible to the unaided eye. Think bleeding-edge technology. My retort to the assertion that "there is no chip" is, then upon what principle or mechanism does this technology operate? Because this IS happening, and I am not crazy. You can find news articles about neuroscientists who are able to have their thoughts read via a brain-computer interface. Is it that farfetched that someone may have developed the tech further?

All I will say is this: imagine the great leaps in neuroscience that could be made if an organization decided to completely disregard things such as Institutional Review Boards, medical ethics, or even human rights and just went gung-ho for the science, doing experimental brain surgery all willy-nilly on their incredibly unlucky victims. Imagine the technological developments that could stem from that kind of accelerated research program... At the expense of their test subjects. You saw the horrible injuries that Musk's test monkeys were suffering from for the Neuralink. Just extrapolate...

"are able to have their thoughts read via a brain-computer interface" neuroscience is not even close to read thoughts. There are some Epi-phenomena in the field of electromagnetic activity related to movement activity that can be used to generate control signals. However, these often only work in a scientific scenario and are not usable for everyday life. Long story short, this technology does not exist and we are far ... far away from it.
